# Is there a property that indicates a ListItem has been shared?

Tags: sharepoint-online, csom, 2019

I need to extract sharing information for list items, I'm currently doing this with `ObjectSharingInformation.GetObjectSharingInformation` using the securableObject overload and passing the list item.

This works and I'm able to extract the info I need. However, I have to call this for every list item even though I know there are very few list items that have actually been shared. This results in many unnecessary requests and 429 `Too many requests` responses. I'm handling these with incremental retries but would like to avoid them altogether.

So, is there a property or field value I can check on the list item I already have that would indicate that the item has been shared? I'd like to limit my calls to `GetObjectSharingInformation` to only those items I know have actually been shared.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There is no specific [property](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/microsoft.sharepoint.client.objectsharinginformation?view=sharepoint-csom) for if an item “*have actually been shared*”.

Consider using `ObjectSharingInformation.SharingLinks` to retrieve only items with Sharing Links generated.

See a reference here for SharePoint Online: [Generating Sharing Links Report And Removing Sharing Links Using SharePoint Online CSOM.](https://www.c-sharpcorner.com/article/generating-sharing-links-report-and-removing-sharing-links-using-sharepoint-onli/)

Comment: Thanks, looking at the link you provided it would suggest that only items that have 'HasUniqueRoleAssignments' set to true might be good enough to restrict the number of requests - as the majority will inherit the role assignments from their parent. Is it safe to assume that this property is set when an item is shared?

Comment: @Ademund Yes. Once you create a sharing link for an item, unique permission is assigned at the item level, and so is the property “HasUniqueRoleAssignments” set to true.